# How to organize validate a form on client side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation, client, client-side

I have modal window, which pop up via ajax (my data and form are loading in this modal window).

My modal and form

```
<div id="name_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

partial with modal-body

```
<div class="modal-body">
<%= form_for(@user, :url => update_name_user_registration_path,
  :html => { :id => "form_name_phone", :method => :put }, :remote => true) do |f| %>

       <div><%= f.label :name, t('form.name') %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %></div>
        <div><%= f.label :phone_number %><br />
        <%= t('form.phone_notice' )%><br />
        <%= f.text_field :phone_number, :maxlength => 10 %></div> 

  <div><%= f.submit t('users.update') %></div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Then I also send data via AJAX.

How to organize validate this form on client side?

Answer (score 1):

Check this rails cast [client side validation](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations). This gem will help you validate on all element on form, or each element. It uses validates you defined in your model.

Example if your user model has this validate:

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

Then in your form, add `validate: true`:

```
<%= form_for(@user, validate: true, :url => update_name_user_registration_path,
  :html => { :id => "form_name_phone", :method => :put }, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

This will check `name` on form must be presence. If you have validates for other attributes in model, they will be validated too.

Comment: I tried this, but it's doesn't work with ajax in my application. Or I do it wrong. Maybe you have a full example? I saw http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations, but nothing happened.

Comment: This is validate fields on form at time you click on it and move to other field. If you want to send data use Ajax, then you should write more code to do it. This [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax) has a guide to work with Ajax, check it to know how to make ajax work.